# Why can't my customized qlabel class control the label on the UI interface？

Tags: c++, qt

To enable qlabel to respond to click events, I inherit a new class(myLabel) from the qlabel class.
When mylabel is clicked, the text of qlabel on the UI interface will be changed. I use public functions (mylabelSetUi()) from MainWindow to implement it because some parameters (lb_row & lb_colunm) come from mylabel.
Now qdebug() in the function shows that the data has been successfully transferred, but the text content of qlabel cannot be changed.

I hide redundant code for easy reading.

> myLabel.cpp

```
#include "mylabel.h"
#include <ui_mainwindow.h>
#include <QDebug>
#include <mainwindow.h>
myLabel::myLabel(QByteArray temInLabel,QWidget *parent)
    :QLabel(parent)
{
    num = temInLabel;
    connect(this,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(slotClicked()));
}
myLabel::~myLabel()
{
}
void myLabel::slotClicked()
{
    myLabel::moveCursor();
}
void myLabel::moveCursor()//移动光标
{
    bool flag;
    int order = this->objectName().toInt(&flag,10);
    int lb_column = order%45;//列数
    int lb_row=floor(order/45);//行数
    MainWindow others ;
    /*When I use public functions, I find that I need a MainWindow object. So I created a new one.
      But it works badly. I'm sure the problem is here, but I can't find a way to solve it*/
    others.mylabelSetUi(QString::number(lb_row,10),num.at(this->objectName().toInt(&flag,10)));
}
void myLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)
{
    emit clicked();
}
```

> mainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <mylabel.h>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QTextStream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
    ,scaleFactor(1)//
    ,ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->showMaximized();
    initRightInterface();
}
void MainWindow::mylabelSetUi(QString x, char y)
{
    ui->label_ts->setText(x);
    ui->label_20->setText(QString(y));
    qDebug()<<"x="<<x<<"y="<<y;
}
void MainWindow::initRightInterface()
{
    QGridLayout *gbox = new QGridLayout;
    imageWidget = new QWidget;
    for(int i=0;i<tem.size();i++)
    {
        lb[i] = new myLabel(tem,this);
        lb[i]->setObjectName(QString::number(i));
        lb[i]->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/image/"+QString(tem.at(i))+".png"));
        lb[i]->setScaledContents(true);
        gbox->addWidget(lb[i],floor(i/45),i%45,1,1,Qt::AlignCenter);
    }
    gbox->setSpacing(0);
    gbox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    imageWidget->setLayout(gbox);
    ui->scrollArea->setWidget(imageWidget);
    ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(false);
}
```

> mainwindow.h

```
public:
    QByteArray tem = "124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124"
                     "124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124"
                     "124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124124";
    //These numbers are used to represent the pictures displayed on mylabel
```

[image]

Comment: `floor(order/45)` is completely redundant. Integer division always rounds down, and by the time you call `floor` the integer division has already been done. The division isn't done in floating-point at all

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of code (probably not required for reproducing the issue), but the logic comes down to this:

1. You need to make the connection from the controlling label to the target label.
2. When the mousePressEvent() is hit, you call `setText()` on the target label. If you need to emit a signal and not call the label method directly, you can do so.

However, this push button behaviour as a QLabel sender does not seem to be natural. If you would like to change an image on your UI when clicking on something, this is what `QPushButton` is meant for. And then, you can just use the `clicked()` signal with `QObject::connect`

Comment: It seems that my inaccurate description is misleading. I uploaded a picture of my UI. I hope the clicked label and the label displaying the data are not the same label. I use code to implement the sublabel on the right, but the qlabel on the left is placed in the UI designer

Answer (score 0):

I think I can give a little suggestion to this question I asked a year ago.

1. Use `QGraphicsPixmap` and `QGraphicsScene&view` to manage a large number of graphics classes, don't use `QLabel`;
   Inherit a subclass `Pix` from `QGraphicsPixmap`, and determine the image to be loaded through the passed parameters in the subclass content.
   like this

```cpp
class pix : public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
public:
    explicit pix(int pixData = 0);
```

2. **About click response**

- Don't think about implementing event response on items. It is very laborious to `conncet` every item. My approach is to create a `QHash<QString, yourDataTYpe>` for item

```cpp
    pix *item_high = new pix(high_four,x,y,rowNum,IMAGE_SIZE);
    item_high->setPos(QPoint(x,y));
    scene->addItem(item_high);
    insertHash(x, y, rowNum, high_four);
    x +=IMAGE_SIZE;
```

- Then rewrite the `mousePressEvent` function of the `QGraphicsView`

```cpp
void myGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        QPointF scenePos = mapToScene(event->pos());
        // qDebug() << "Click on scene coordinates: " << scenePos;
        emit sendScenePos(scenePos.x(), scenePos.y());
    }
    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

- To emit this signal to the UI file, process it in the slot function. You can process the currently obtained `x` and `y` axis data to obtain the corresponding item value in `QHash`.